# Cascade Delete is not work

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I am not able to delete record from parent table of PostGres DB.. Any one of you can get me an idea on this.

```
-- Table: tbl_patient

-- DROP TABLE tbl_patient;

CREATE TABLE tbl_patient
(
 patient_id bigserial NOT NULL,
 date_of_birth date NOT NULL,
 fathers_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 first_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 last_name character varying(255),
 marital_status character varying(255),
 mobile_number character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 occupation character varying(255),
 phone_number character varying(255),
 pregnancy_status character varying(255),
 sex character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT tbl_patient_pkey PRIMARY KEY (patient_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tbl_patient
OWNER TO postgres;


-- Table: tbl_address

CREATE TABLE tbl_address
(
 address_id bigserial NOT NULL,
 address_line_1 character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 address_line_2 character varying(255),
 city character varying(255),
 country character varying(255),
 district character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 pincode character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 state character varying(255),
 street character varying(255),
 patient_id bigint,
 CONSTRAINT tbl_address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (address_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_slc6pgeimmox5buka8bydy6c4 FOREIGN KEY (patient_id)
  REFERENCES tbl_patient (patient_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
 );
 ALTER TABLE tbl_address
   OWNER TO postgres;
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

When I put this command

```
 DELETE FROM tbl_patient
  WHERE patient_id = 1;
```

I got this error below

> ERROR: update or delete on table "tbl_patient" violates foreign key
>   constraint "fk_slc6pgeimmox5buka8bydy6c4" on table "tbl_address" SQL
>   state: 23503 Detail: Key (patient_id)=(1) is still referenced from
>   table "tbl_address".

Comment: There is no problem with your code. It works just fine. Even after adding a row in the 'tbl_patient' table, it deletes just fine. Look for problems elsewhere. If possible, create a new database and try it over there. You will see it works.

Comment: and where are you "putting this command"? and what does it have to do with JPA API?

Answer (score 2):

You write `DELETE NO ACTION` and you wanting actions:) Just need to change to

```
    REFERENCES tbl_patient (patient_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```

`NO ACTION` means that server wont do anything with referenced rows if they exists. Since they exists and you specified also `MATCH SIMPLE` to one-column-foreign key then PostgreSQL cannot perform deletion because of that referenced rows.